# solution verification write the permutation in cycle notation and find the inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, permutations

Definition 1.4.1: A permutation of a set  is a bijection (one-to-one and onto) : → .

Write the permutation in cycle form

$\sigma =$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 5  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

My guess is that I leave out $3,4$ and obtain:

$(1,2),(5,6)$

The inverse is just:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 5 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are right, and you are,  it is its own inverse , because the transpositions are disjoint, hence commute.  And transpositions have order $2$.

Comment: can you explain transpositions and when they are or aren't disjoint

Comment: Sure.  They are disjoint when they don't move any of the same elements.  So when none of the same numbers appear.

Comment: Any transposition, $(ij)$, just interchanges $i$ and $j$, leaving everything else fixed.  So it will have order $2$.